# C# passing Func with parameters where 1 parameter is set while passing and the others are set inside

Tags: c#, function, parameters, func

Hi have created this method to read from excel:

```
        public static Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel> ExcelReader(FileUploadModel upload,
            Func<Dictionary<int, string>, Row, object, Action> func)
        {
            try
            {
                var dict = new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>();
                using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(upload.Stream, false))
                {
                    var workbookPart = doc.WorkbookPart;

                    var worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

                    var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();

                    var stringTable = LoadSharedStringDictionarySax(workbookPart.SharedStringTablePart);

                    foreach (var r in sheetData.Elements<Row>())
                    {
                        func(stringTable, r, dict);
                    }
                }

                upload.Stream.Close();

                upload.UploadCompletion = 100;

                return dict;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I call this method in other class like this:

```
private async Task OnFilesDropped(FileUploadModel upload)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>();

    OfficeHelper.ExcelExtension.ExcelReader(upload, ExcelToProjTree);
}

private static Action ExcelToProjTree(Dictionary<int, string> stringTable, Row r, Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel> dict)
{
  //Some stuff
}
```

The stringTable and r are set when the method is called but the dict I wanted to be set when I call ExcelReader

like this somehow:

```
private async Task OnFilesDropped(FileUploadModel upload)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>();

    OfficeHelper.ExcelExtension.ExcelReader(upload, () => ExcelToProjTree(dict));
}
```

Is it possible? if yes, how?

Comment: Change the parameter type of `func` to `Func<Dictionary<int, string>, Row, Action>` then pass `(stringTable, r) => ExcelToProjTree(stringTable, r, dict)` at the call site.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen and inside the foreach where I call it what should I put there?

Comment: `func(stringTable, r);` (since you've already provided the `dict` argument inside the lambda)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I will try that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you'll be supplying a static `object` parameter argument (this is known as [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) btw), you'll want to remove that from the parameter list of the resulting `Func` type:

```
public static Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel> ExcelReader(FileUploadModel upload,
        Func<Dictionary<int, string>, Row, Action> func) { /* */ }
```

Then make sure the lambda you supply as an argument to `ExcelReader` has the correct signature as well (it should still accept `Dictionary<int, string>` and `Row` arguments):

```
OfficeHelper.ExcelExtension.ExcelReader(upload, (stringTable, row) => ExcelToProjTree(stringTable, row, dict));
```

And finally update the invocation of the function so that you only pass the first two parameter arguments:

```
func(stringTable, r); // `dict` will automatically be bound inside of `func`
```

Given that `func` still returns an `Action`, you might want to invoke that right away:

```
func(stringTable, r)();
```

Comment: By calling func(stringTable, r)(); I get the following exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." the Action is returning null, so I should leave it without the () right?

Comment: It worked like a sharm! thank you for being helpful I had never done functional programming before ;)

Comment: @MarchalPT You're welcome! If you don't actually intend to return an `Action`, you might want to change the signature of `func` to `Action<Dictionary<int, string>, Row>`

Comment: So Actions are methods that return void and fucn are methods that return always something right?

Comment: Correct. So if `func` is a "fire and forget" function (eg. nothing returned), then `Action` is probably a more appropriate type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Lazy<T>`

```cs
private Lazy<Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>> dict;

// Constructor
public YourClass()
{
    this.dict = Lazy<Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>>(
        () => ExcelToProjTree(new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>()));
}

private async Task OnFilesDropped(FileUploadModel upload)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, TreeItemModel>();

    // ExcelToProjTree Will be eveluated only now
    OfficeHelper.ExcelExtension.ExcelReader(upload, () => dict.Value);
}
```